# .mp4 video icon (not thumbnail) showing incorrectly

Tags: windows-7, video, media-player-classic

I've just noticed an issue with some video files. This only appears to happen for .mp4 files, and not other video formats.

If you look below, the "Kung Fury Official Trailer" shows a thumbnail, and the Media Player Classic Icon. This is as I would expect.

The "Paperman" short video shows a thumbnail, and an icon for a folder, which isn't as expected.

From looking around, it seems that a program could have modified the registry, but I haven't installed or uninstalled anything (that I know of) to change it. How do I change the icons back?
[image]

Comment: what app is mp4 associated with? Try changing it to something else, check icon, change it back to your preferred.

Comment: @Tetsujin - it was set with Media Player Classic, however setting it again sorted the issue. If you post your answer as a comment I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something may have changed the file associations, or default app for that file type.

Simplest would be to just change it to something else, then back again to your preferred app.
Also check the Default Programs control panel says all defaults are set

[image]